# apply for .pcm file as sox

Tags: mp3, wav, pcm, sox

I want to exchange  16kHz pcm --> 48kHz wav using sox.
however, pcm file isn't applied in sox.

so, I just changed pcm to raw, 
and then
sox -r 16000 -e signed -b 16 -c 1 test.raw -r 48000 out.wav

Can I apply for pcm file not convert raw?

Answer (score 3):

For the PCM file, since PCM's are headerless, you need to add '-t raw' as the *first* argument.

```
sox -t raw -r 16000 -e signed -b 16 -c 1 test.raw -r 48000 out.wav
```

Try that out.

Also try the different Endian settings; -L; -B; -x
though only use one at a time, and only if not using one doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to convert the input file into raw. Sox can handle pcm files.

```
sox input.pcm -r 48000 output.wav
```

The input file can either be a .pcm or .wav.

Since .wav files have a header containing audio metadata (such as sample rate, bit precision, file length, etc), you don't have to pass any information about the input file. Hence, non need to use:

```
-r 16000 -e signed -b 16 -c 1
```

Converting pcm to raw you have just stripped down the file header.

Comment: no, it does not work for 'pcm' , I am getting us error "$ sox file_32.pcm -r 48000 output.wav
C:\Program Files (x86)\sox-14-4-2\sox.exe FAIL formats: no handler for file extension `pcm'"

Comment: @MMH, it does work for pcm, only if you don't name the input file with `.pcm` extension, use `.raw`.